# PHP - returning an empty string using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am facing the reality of using mysqli vs. mysql.  I have the following function that sanitize data

This is how the code was using mysql

```
  function sanitize($data){
      return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($data)));
  }
```

Error message when using **mysql**

```
   Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in...
```

after reading php manual reference on https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string  and made the changes below...

```
  function sanitize($data){
      return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($data, '0')));
  }
```

...I receive the following Error message after using **mysqli**

```
  Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in....
```

This is now preventing me from logging in.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You read `mysqli $link , string $escapestr` in the manual and change your code to `$data, '0'`? There're many examples if you can't understand the syntax of the manual.

Comment: yes! I have been learning php for 2 months now...I know it may seem not wise at all!!!  my apologies, I wish I can grasp this stuff much quicker and faster.  It is not that easy sometime, especially when I am following a tutorial.  the hands on is a great way  to learn but it will require some time to get the hang of the logic behind what is being developed. As I said my apologies...

Comment: BTW, your function is called `sanitize()` but a more proper name would be `mangle()` or `corrupt()`. If you read that in a tutorial I suggest you find another reference text—that code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Alvaro, thank you for your comment, i intend to learn more about php and hopefully the proper way.  at the beginning, it is easier to work with something, but I agree with you!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string):

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

---

**Why do you need database connection to escape a string?!**

The string escape function **needs to know** which **encoding** your database connection uses to properly escape the strings. So you have to pass the connection to the function.

The function `mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $str)` has something like this in it:

```
$encoding = $mysqli->getConnectionEncoding();
```

This is why you have to pass the connection.

This modern software design pattern (pass something that is needed inside a class through the constructor or as a function's param) is called *dependency injection* (short *DI pattern*).

---

A yet better way would be to use the OOP style:

```
$con           = new mysqli();
$escapedString = $con->real_escape_string($string);
```

Answer (score 4):

`Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli` is pretty self explanatory...

You need to provide your `mysqli` instance as the first parameter, and your string as the second parameter.

E.g.

`mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, $data)`

Comment: so I take it, establishing a connection through a init.php file is not suffice..mysqli requires to pass the connection as a parameter.  thanks Ryan!!

Comment: Unless you use the Scope Resolution Operator (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) `mysqli::real_escape_string($data)` where the link is already set the instance you're referencing.